# Laravel not preserving a session/cookie after redirection

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

I need some information to be preserved in a session(or cookie) even after multiple redirects. i stored it in a session(in a controller method) using

```
Session::put('product_quantity', $productQuantity);
```

and then tried to use it another method using

```
Session::get('product_quantity');
```

but it gives `null`. Same problem with cookies.

I checked that `storage/frameworks/session` is writable. Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Which `Session` driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

first check session is created or not
use `Session::has(sessionName)` in if condition

and you can also get session value by

```
$val= session('sessionkey')
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the configuration problem. Once check the driver in config/session.php file. Try changing to native it may work.